# Postgresql service run failure

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, replication, write-ahead-logging

Trying to setup replication through the wal shipping using Postgresql 9.3 x64.

[Used this instruction from youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zq4zS0ZbXsc).

The problem is - the slave postgresql service won't run.
This is what in logs

```
IST FATAL:  ShmemIndex entry size is wrong for data
structure "Wal Sender Ctl": expected 144, actual 56
```

Comment: Well, that's different. Are you certain both ends are x64?

Comment: Yep. I got 2 identical win7 virtual machines